# Using Prism to Inject and Navigate Views?

Tags: c#, xaml

So I have been trying to learn Prism and use it with my project. I am also trying to use the MVVM pattern. So basically, I want a experts advice or opinion on how I setup my program. I've been trying to get a View to display inside my shell on startup, and the ability to navigate from View to View. Here is my code:

My BootStrapper.cs:
(Initializes the Shell.)

```
    public class EquinoxBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    #region MainShell Initialization

    //MainShell Initialization

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Views.MainShell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    #endregion
    #region Containers

    //Containers

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        #region Region Register Zone
        //register views here!
        //Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.Splash), "Splash");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.LoginView), "LoginView");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.Dashboard), "Dashboard");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.SettingsView), "SettingsView");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Views.UserCreationView), "UserCreationView");
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
    #region Modules

    //Modules

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        base.InitializeModules();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return base.CreateModuleCatalog();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My MainShell.xaml:
(Has my ContentControl Region.)

```
<Window x:Name="Shell" 
    x:Class="Equinox.Views.MainShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="Equinox"
    FontFamily="Quicksand"
    Height="800" 
    Width="1200"
    Background="#EEF3F4"
    Icon="/Equinox;component/favicon.ico"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Grid>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ViewMainFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

My MainShellViewModel.cs:
(Contains my Region Manager.)

```
    public class MainShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    #region Private Variables

    //Private Variables

    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    #endregion
    #region Public Variables

    //Public Variables

    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Functions and Methods

    //Functions and Methods

    public MainShellViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        //Region Manager
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        //Startup View
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ViewMainFrame", typeof(Views.Dashboard));
    }

    public void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        //Navigation
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ViewMainFrame", uri);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I run it, the view (Dashboard) is Injected into the MainShell on Startup. Am I doing this correctly? It seems to work, but I just want to make sure that there is nothing I am missing. I plan on making buttons inside each View where I can easily navigate from view to view. If you know of a way that will fit with my already built application can you guide me in the correct direction to make Prism Navigation easier too? One last thing, the tutorial I followed had me make Containers, will that work with my navigation? I noticed some tutorials talked about Modules, is there a difference?

Thanks!